# Understanding Alexandroff compactification

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, compactness

Is the Alexandroff one-point compactification of a locally compact Hausdorff space ($\mathbf{LCHaus}$) a functor to the category of compact Hausdorff spaces ($\mathbf{CHaus}$)? It seems to me that one has to consider only *proper* continuous maps as morphisms.

If one does so, then the most natural definition for the induced map $\hat f\colon\hat X\to \hat Y$ seems to work (just send $x\mapsto f(x)$ and $\infty_X\mapsto \infty_Y$, continuity has to be checked only on open sets containing $\infty$) but a lot of interesting situations seem to be excluded: one hopes that (e.g.) a map $h\colon (0,1)\to \mathbb R$ such that $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}h(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}h(x)$$
admits an extension $\hat h\colon \widehat{(0,1)}\to \mathbb R$; but what if $h$ is not proper? It is "outside" the category I'm considering. So:

1. How can one define suitable topological categories between which $\widehat{(-)}$ is a functor?
2. Morally a compactification should be a left adjoint to an inclusion (in this case $\iota\colon \mathbf{CHaus}\hookrightarrow\mathbf{LCHaus}$), but even if it seems evident that (taking only proper maps) $$\hom_{\mathbf{CHaus}}(\hat X,Y)\cong \hom_{\mathbf{LCHaus}}(X,\iota Y)$$ the Alexandroff correspondence seems to be ill-behaved with respect to colimits... is there any hope to make $X\mapsto \hat X$ adjoint to something?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Just looking at coproducts, the target category would have to be some category of pointed spaces, with coproducts given by wedge sums.

Comment: Indeed, according to the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension#The_one-point_compactification the Alexandroff extension can be viewed as a functor from the category of topological spaces to the category whose objects are continuous maps $c: X \rightarrow Y$ and for which the morphisms from $c_1: X_1 \rightarrow Y_1$ to $c_2: X_2 \rightarrow Y_2$ are pairs of continuous maps $f_X: X_1 \rightarrow X_2, \ f_Y: Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ such that $f_Y \circ c_1 = c_2 \circ f_X$... This seems highly unsatisfactory.

Comment: I was asking you to check if my argument is correct. Does restricting to proper maps affect colimits in such a way that the one-point compactification functor respects them? I was also asking if the categories I'm considering are "the right ones", in view of the wiki page I quoted...

Comment: the "evident" adjunction you state can't be true for yet another reason: pre-images of compact sets under proper maps are compact and as $Y$ is compact, $X$ would have to be...

Comment: Thank you t.b., this is another point I forgot to write down in the OP... So, is all gone?

Comment: Let $Y$ be a compact and $X$ a non compact, locally compact space. Maybe $\hom(X,Y)$ is empty if I restrict only to proper maps, which seems to sensibly trivialize the adjunction...

Comment: One should carefully distinguish Alexandroff **compactification** (that is defined for non-compact spaces only) and Alexandroff **extension** (that is defined on any topological space, but introduces a new connectivity component if it was already compact). The former is certainly not a functor on **LCHaus**.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathsf{LCH}$ be the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces with proper continuous maps and $\mathsf{CH}$ be the full subcategory of compact Hausdorff spaces with continuous maps. We extend it to the category $\mathsf{CH}_*$ of pointed compact Hausdorff spaces with pointed continuous maps. The Alexandrov compactification is a functor $$A : \mathsf{LCH} \to \mathsf{CH}_*.$$
Of course, we choose $\infty$ to be our base point. Unfortunately, it is not left adjoint to the forgetful functor $U : \mathsf{CH}_* \to \mathsf{LCH}$. However, it has the following universal property:

For $X \in \mathsf{LCH}$ and $(Y,y_0) \in \mathsf{CH}_*$ we say that a continuous map $f : X \to Y$ is *proper away from $y_0$* if for all compact subsets $K \subseteq Y$ with $y_0 \notin K$ the preimage $f^{-1}(K)  \subseteq X$ is compact. We obtain a set $\mathrm{Hom}_{y_0}(X,Y)$ and it is easy to see that
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{CH}_*}(A(X),(Y,y_0)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{y_0}(X,Y).$$
Notice that the left hand side (strictly) contains $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{LCH}}(X,U(Y,y_0))$, the set of proper continuous maps $X \to Y$. It is quite instructive to consider the special case $X=\mathbb{N}$, where maps are just sequences and "properness away from $y_0$" precisely means convergence to $y_0$.

It is easy to check that $A$ preserves finite coproducts. But it does not preserve infinite coproducts. For example, $(A(\{n\}) \to A(\mathbb{N}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  is not a coproduct diagram in $\mathsf{CH}_*$, because this would mean that every sequence converges. In particular, $A$ is not left adjoint to any functor.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to get a functor out of Alexandroff compactification, even though it requires significant changes:

Let $\mathsf{LCH}_\hookrightarrow$ be the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces and **open embeddings**, and $\mathsf{CH}_*$ the category of pointed compact Hausdorff spaces and pointed continuous maps. Then there is a **contravariant** functor
$$\widehat{(-)} : \mathsf{LCH}_\hookrightarrow^{\rm op} \to \mathsf{CH}_*$$
given by Alexandroff *extension*<sup>$\dagger$</sup> on spaces. If $f : X \hookrightarrow Y$ is an open embedding of LCH spaces, there is an induced map $f^* : \hat{Y} \to \hat{X}$ where:
$$f^*(y) =
\begin{cases}
x & y = f(x), \\
* & y \not\in \operatorname{im}(f).
\end{cases}$$
Note that the base point $* \in \hat{Y}$ is not in the image of $f$ so gets mapped to the base point $* \in \hat{X}$. It's not hard to check that this is continuous, because $f$ was an open embedding. Finally, it's clear that the construction is functorial.

---

<sup>$\dagger$</sup> If the space is already compact, this isn't a compactification -- see Incnis Mrsi's comment.

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer the "adjoint" question, but since it's contravariant and not covariant I'm not sure what the adjoint should be...